# How to format a text area sent as an array via JSON?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, json

I'm pretty new to Ruby, and I'm using it work with an API. Text area's sent over the API are converted to the format below before being sent to me via a JSON POST request:

```
"Comment": [
        "hdfdhgdfgdfg\r",
        "This is just a test\r",
        "Thanks!\r",
        "- Kyle"
    ]
```

And I'm getting the value like this:

```
comments = params["Comment"]
```

So each line is broken down into what looks like an array. My issue is, it functions just like one big string instead of an array with 4 values. I tried using `comments[0]` and just printing `comments` but both return the same result, it just displays everything as a string, ie

```
["hdfdhgdfgdfg\r", "This is just a test\r", "Thanks!\r", "- Kyle"]
```

But I need to display it as it appears in the text area, ie

```
hdfdhgdfgdfg
This is just a test
Thanks!
- Kyle
```

I know I could just strip out all the extra characters, but I feel like there has to be a better way. Is there a good way to convert this back to the original format of a text area, or at least to convert it to an array so I can loop through each item and re-format it?

Comment: the posted result is already an array, if it is not an array you can split it on carriage return comments[0].split("\r"), and you will get the array of each line

Comment: thats where my problem lies, it looks like an array but functions like a string

Comment: can you post the exact output of comments[0]

Comment: I did, it's a string of `["hdfdhgdfgdfg\r", "This is just a test\r", "Thanks!\r", "- Kyle"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get rid of those ugly `\r`s:

```
comments.map!(&:chomp)
```

Then, join the lines together:

```
comment = comments.join("\n") # using a newline
# OR, for HTML output:
comment = comments.join('<br>')
```

Comment: Perfect, this did it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to parse the JSON and populate a hash with all of the values:

```
require 'json' 

hash = JSON.parse(params["Comment"])

puts hash

=> {"Comment"=>['all', 'of', 'your', 'values']}
```

**This should work for all valid json**. One of the rules of json syntax is that

> Data is in name/value pairs

The json you provided doesn't supply names for the values, therefore this method might not work.  If this is the case, parsing the raw string and extracting values would do the job as well (although more messy).

How you might go about doing that:

```
json = params["Comment"]
newArray = []

json.split(" ").each do |element|
  if element.length > 1
    newArray << element
  end
end
```

This would at least give you an array with all of your values.

Comment: I tried this, unfortunately it still gives the same result

Comment: Thanks, but still no luck. `params["Comment"]` is still being interpreted as a string, even though it looks like an array.

Comment: You'll probably need the workaround, explained at the bottom of the answer